# If $‎\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1‎$,‎ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

‎Suppose ‎$‎f‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎g‎$‎ ‎‎are real functions such that $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1‎$‎‎. ‎My ‎question ‎is‎:

‎‎‎
‎‎What other condition is required ‏‎that $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎?‎

‎‎ 
‎Generall‏‎y,‎ $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1‎\nRightarrow‎‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0‎$‎. ‏‎For ‎example, ‎‎$‎f(x) = x^2 + x‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎g(x) =‎ ‎x^2‎$‎.‎

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that from $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ you get
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}=0.$$

For example, if you have additional information that the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} g(x)=L$ exists and is *finite*, then you get
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-g(x)) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}\cdot g(x) = 0\cdot L = 0.$$

In fact, even a bit weaker assumption that $g(x)$ is bounded is enough. Take any $\varepsilon>0$. You have $|g(x)|\le M$ for some real number $M$ and each $x$ and
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}\right| \le \varepsilon$$ for every large enough $x$. Then you get
$$|f(x)-g(x)| = \left|\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}\right| \cdot |g(x)| \le \varepsilon M$$
for $x\ge x_0$ (where $x_0$ depends on $\varepsilon$), i.e.,
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty} |f(x)-g(x)| \le \varepsilon M.$$
Since this is true for every $\varepsilon > 0$ (and $M$ is fixed), you get $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty} |f(x)-g(x)| = 0$ and
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-g(x)) = 0.$$

Answer (score 5):

You need $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ where both $h(x) = o(1)$ and $h(x) = o[g(x)]$.

... or stated more precisely by Mark Viola, these are necessary and sufficient conditions.

For example, if  $f(x) = e^{-x}+ 1/x$ and $g(x)= e^{-x}$, then the second condition is violated. In your example, the first condition is violated.

Comment: (+1)  All too easy.

Comment: You might consider adding that while "You need ..." that those conditions suffice also.  That is, they are necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @MarkViola: Thanks.  That is stated more precisely.

Comment: Your condition is necessary and sufficient for the OP's two conditions to both hold. However, given the OP's first condition, the last part of your condition is redundant, while the rest of it is just a restatement of the OP's second condition.

Comment: Mark viola.What condition do I need to answer my question?

Answer (score 3):

The conditions (A) $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=1$ and (B) $\lim_{x\to\infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$ are pretty much unrelated. For example, $f(x):=2/x$ and $g(x):=1/x$ satisfy B but not A, while your example shows independence in the other direction. Any "additional" condition that implies B will need to be, essentially, a statement of B itself (or something stronger). Condition A won't be making a useful contribution.

Answer (score 2):

$‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0‎$ is stronger than $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1‎.$  If $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x\geq x_0$ and $g(x) \neq o(1)$ we have

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0 \implies \displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1.$$

The other implication is not true all the time; see that 
$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1 \iff f(x) = g(x) + o(g(x))$$

and

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0 \iff f(x) = g(x) + o(1).$$

Comment: jgon. If ‎$‎f(x) =  ‎\frac{1}{x}‎‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎g(x) = ‎\frac{1}{x^2}‎‎$, ‎then‎ $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0‎$ ‎but 
‎‎$‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = ‎\infty‎‎$‎‏. ‎Notice  that ‎‎$‎g(x)\neq ‎0‎$‎.‎
‎

Comment: You have right, the case $\dfrac{0}{0}$ gives this problem, we should take off this case

Answer (score 1):

For this to be true we need the $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)$ to exist and be finite or the functions can be such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=\pm\infty$ but then we need that $f=g$.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0‎$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)) - \lim_{x\to\infty}(g(x)) = 0‎$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)) = \lim_{x\to\infty}(g(x))‎$$

Comment: I think $f(x) = x + 1/x$ and $g(x) = x $ contradicts your statement about needing  $f=g$ when both limits are infinite.

Comment: Yes it does. I am unsure what the conditions are required for functions with infinite limits then. Maybe by using l'Hopitals rule we can say that $f^{(n)}=g^{(n)}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$?