# Does $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ imply that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)-g(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, intuition

On an intuitive level, it would seem that
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\implies\lim_{x\to0}f(x)-g(x)=0
$$
If the quotient of two quantities is approaching $1$, then the two quantities would have to be getting closer together. However, I'm not quite sure if the above statement is true for all functions $f,g$. More generally, is the following statement true?
$$
\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\iff\lim_{x\to c}f(x)-g(x)=0
$$

Comment: Have you tried polynomials for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $‎\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}‎\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1‎$,‎ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0‎$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115413/if-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fracfxgx-1-then-lim-limits-x-to)

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm not sure this is a duplicate. of course it is strictly related and more general. Here the doubt is also on the intuition of what is going on and related counterexamples.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I agree with user's comment. However, thanks for providing the link anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many counterexamples have been provided, but there are simpler (an more illuminating, I think)

$$f(x) = \frac1{x} \quad g(x) = 1 + \frac1{x}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let consider as counterexample

$$f(x)=\ln x+\frac1{x}, \quad g(x)=\frac1{x}$$

such that

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =x\ln x+1 \to 0+1=1$$

but

$$f(x)-g(x)=\ln x \to -\infty$$

Comment: Hi user. Thanks for responding to my question. It is quite clear that I was wrong, and your example proves it, so I need to re-wire my intuitions a little bit. I'm still struggling to understand the fault in my logic: 'if the quotient of two quantities is approaching $1$, then the two quantities should be approaching each other'. What part of that statement is flawed? (Just a hint would suffice.)

Comment: @Joe In this example you can see what is the point. We have that $1/x$ grows up mre that $\ln x$ then in the limit the term $x\ln x$ vanishes. But for the difference $\ln x$ survives. The example by Physor works in the same way and of course we can findmany others examples.

Comment: I see. So $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are *always* $\ln x$ apart (and in fact they become 'infinitely apart'). However, when we consider $$\frac{\ln x + 1/x}{1/x}$$, $1/x$ grows to $\infty$ more quickly than $\ln x$ grows to $-\infty$. So ultimately $\ln x$ becomes negligible.

Comment: @Joe Yes that's how we can construct counterexamples in thsi case.

Comment: Thanks user. It now makes intuitive sense to me. By the way, do we only have to consider the right-hand limit as $\ln x$ is undefined for $x<0$?

Comment: @Joe This depends upon the definition/notation we are referring to. Anyway to exclude this issue we can just take $\ln |x|$. Note that the same proble there exists for $1/\sqrt x$.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with complex numbers, so you'll have to forgive my ignorance. Does $\ln x$ (the complex-valued logarithm) still grow towards $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from the left?

Comment: @Joe My suggestion is to take the absolute value for $x$ such that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \ln |x|=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln |x|=\lim_{x \to 0^-} \ln |x|=-\infty$$

Answer (score 4):

Were it so easy!

The Prime Number Theorem says that if $\pi(x)$ counts the number of primes less than or equal to $x$,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x/\log(x)}=1
$$If your claim were true, then eventually, say for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$, $|\pi(x)-x/\log(x)|<1/2$ for $x\ge M$. But since $\pi(x)$ is clearly an integer, *this would give a closed-form for $\pi(x)$* (provided we knew $M$). As of this writing, however, such a formula is not known.

Comment: This answer deals with limits at infinity instead of at a real number $c$, but the idea is identical (and can be translated to limits at zero by a substitution $z\mapsto 1/x$).

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=g(x) +h(x) $ such that $\lim h(x) /g(x) =0$ Take any fast growing function $g$ and take any slower function $h$ that satisfies the property.

A simple example is $$g(x) = \frac1{(x-c)^2},h(x)=1$$
For any $c$

Comment: With this example isn't it $f/g=1+1/x$ ?

Comment: @user I saw limit to infinity instead of $0$ and $c$ I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\ ,\qquad g(x) = \frac{1}{x}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 + \sqrt{x}}{1} = 1
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x) - g(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}) = \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

According to you algebraical transformations u have to do following steps:
$$ lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1 $$
$$\frac{\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)}=1$$, then u multiplied both sides by $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ and finally get:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) $$
so it is the same as:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)-\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0 $$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-g(x))=0$$
The problem is when we split limit of a quotient into a quotient of a limit,and same is when we substract limits. We can do it under an assumption that:$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=g_{1} $$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=g_{2}\ne 0 $$ where $-\infty\lt g_{1},g_{2}\lt\infty $ ,
Example, . Remember: while calculating limits, first think you do is to simplify expression inside the limit.
But, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, after writing this I honestly met a problem, because in quotient there oficially should be another assumption that g2=/=0, but as far as i know we can do lim of sinx/x=1 which implies that sinx=x as x goes to 0. Idk why it doesnt holds poprely, maybe my way of thinking is wrong

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x^n+x^{n-1}, g(x) = x^n$
shows no
since
$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}
=1+\dfrac1{x}
\to
1$.

Comment: How $1+1/x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: I did as $x \to \infty$. Take $1/x$ if $\to 0$.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe you should revise, in that way it is really confusing.